# Keep consecutive duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame where one column contains some consecutive duplicates. I want to keep the rows with consecutive duplicates (any length >1). I would prefer a solution in `dplyr` or `data.table`.

Example data :

```
a <- seq(10,150,10)
b <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "E", "E")

df <- tibble(a, b)
```

Data:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
       a b    
   <dbl> <chr>
 1    10 A    
 2    20 A    
 3    30 B    
 4    40 C    
 5    50 C    
 6    60 A    
 7    70 B    
 8    80 B    
 9    90 B    
10   100 C    
11   110 A    
12   120 C    
13   130 D    
14   140 E    
15   150 E
```

So I would like to keep the rows with consecutive duplicates in column `b`.

Expected outcome:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
       a b    
   <dbl> <chr>
 1    10 A    
 2    20 A    
 4    40 C    
 5    50 C    
 7    70 B    
 8    80 B    
 9    90 B          
14   140 E    
15   150 E
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `lag` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`  we can use `lag` to create groups and select groups with more than 1 row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(b != lag(b, default = first(b)))) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#     a  b    
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1    10 A    
#2    20 A    
#3    40 C    
#4    50 C    
#5    70 B    
#6    80 B    
#7    90 B    
#8   140 E    
#9   150 E
```

---

In base R, we can use `rle` and `ave` to `subset` rows from `df`

```
subset(df, ave(b, with(rle(b), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = length) > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the data.table input shown in the Note at the end, set N to be the number of elements in each group of consecutive elements and then keep groups for which it is greater than 1.

```
DT[, N :=.N, by = rleid(b)][N > 1, .(a, b)]
```

giving:

```
     a b
1:  10 A
2:  20 A
3:  40 C
4:  50 C
5:  70 B
6:  80 B
7:  90 B
8: 140 E
9: 150 E
```

### Note

We assume the input in reproducible form is:

```
library(data.table)
a <- seq(10,150,10)
b <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "E", "E")
DT <- data.table(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also have the `data.table` tag, i like using the `data.table::rleid` function for such tasks, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(b), b) %>% 
 filter(n() > 1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 3
> # Groups:   grp, b [4]
>       a b       grp
>   <dbl> <chr> <int>
> 1    10 A         1
> 2    20 A         1
> 3    40 C         3
> 4    50 C         3
> 5    70 B         5
> 6    80 B         5
> 7    90 B         5
> 8   140 E        10
> 9   150 E        10
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove duplicate except when consecutive: the following code flags duplicate values and consecutive values, then keeps only rows that are not duplicate or that are part of a consecutive set of duplicates.

```
df %>%
  mutate(duplicate = duplicated(b), 
         consecutive = c(NA, diff(as.integer(factor(b)))) == 0) %>%
  filter(!duplicate | consecutive) %>%
  select(-duplicate, -consecutive)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rle` to get the run length.

Assuming `df <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)`, then the following can make it

```
df[-cumsum(rle(b)$lengths)[rle(b)$lengths==1],]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution utilizes both `lead()` and `lag()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- seq(10,150,10)
b <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "E", "E")

df <- tibble(a, b)

df %>% filter(b == lead(b) | b == lag(b))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1    10 A    
#> 2    20 A    
#> 3    40 C    
#> 4    50 C    
#> 5    70 B    
#> 6    80 B    
#> 7    90 B    
#> 8   140 E    
#> 9   150 E
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option (which should be faster):

```
D[-D[, {
    x <- rowid(rleid(b)) < 2
    .I[x & shift(x, -1L, fill=TRUE)]
}]]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e7
nb <- 1e4
DT <- data.table(b=sample(nb, nr, TRUE))
#DT <- data.table(b=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "E", "E"))
DT2 <- copy(DT)

mtd1 <- function(df) {
    df[-cumsum(rle(b)$lengths)[rle(b)$lengths==1],]
}

mtd2 <- function(D) {
    D[, N :=.N, by = rleid(b)][N > 1, .(b)]
}

mtd3 <- function(D) {
    D[-D[, {
        x <- rowid(rleid(b)) < 2
        .I[x & shift(x, -1L, fill=TRUE)]
    }]]
}

bench::mark(mtd1(DT), mtd2(DT2), mtd3(DT), check=FALSE)
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result             memory          time    gc            
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>             <list>          <list>  <list>        
1 mtd1(DT)       1.1s     1.1s     0.908    1.98GB    10.9      1    12       1.1s <df[,1] [2,014 x ~ <df[,3] [59 x ~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
2 mtd2(DT2)     2.88s    2.88s     0.348  267.12MB     0        1     0      2.88s <df[,1] [2,014 x ~ <df[,3] [23 x ~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
3 mtd3(DT)   639.91ms 639.91ms     1.56   505.48MB     4.69     1     3   639.91ms <df[,1] [2,014 x ~ <df[,3] [24 x ~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x ~
```